# How to correct masonry.js layout for two columns of different size

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I am having trouble getting my jQuery Masonry layout to work. When I don't use masonry the images are the correct size and position but there are gaps as you would expect.

Masonry should fill those gaps. I think I need to tweak the CSS.

The first image needs to be 741px wide. Because I have set `.grid-item {width:50%}` it reduces the size of the first image.

How do I fix this so that all the images retain their original dimensions but fit next to each other in two columns?

The first image below is with masonry active. The second is with masonry inactive.

```css
.grid {
    max-width: 71em;
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.grid-item {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 7px;
    width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-item" id="grid-item-1"><a href="http://drbl.in/fWMM"><img src="http://grdesigns.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/box-1-741x500.png"></a></div>
 <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item-2"><a href="http://drbl.in/fWPV"><img src="http://grdesigns.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/box-2.png"></a></div>
 <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item-3"><a href="http://drbl.in/fWMT"><img src="http://grdesigns.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/box-3.png"></a></div>
 <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item-4"><a href="http://drbl.in/fQdt"><img src="http://grdesigns.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/box-4.png"></a></div>
        <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item-5"><a href="http://drbl.in/fQdt"><img src="http://grdesigns.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/box-4.png"></a></div>
        </div>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(window).load(function() {
  var container = document.querySelector('.grid');
  var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: '.grid-item',
    horizontalOrder: true,
  });  

    });

</script>
```

[image: With Masonry]

[image: Without Masonry]